# Can't SSH into AWS CloudFormation Stack Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-cloudformation

I have a scalable load balancer set up right now that was mostly followed from this template:

https://github.com/satterly/AWSCloudFormation-samples/blob/master/LAMP_Multi_AZ.template

After adjusting the `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup.CreationPolicy.ResourceSignal.Count` key to `0` (basically allows for stack to load with no success signals received) I was able to load the stack and I can see all resources available.

I can see the public DNS of the keys being created, but I cannot SSH into the instance.

I have a opened up SSH access to everyone within my instance rules, I can confirm this within the AWS console.

I also configured a route for my VPC as recommended within the official AWS docs: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/

I can see the instances exist, but it seems that I am restricting myself access somewhere. However within the AWS EC2 console, the settings *seem* to look the same as when I am able to SSH into an instance.

Here is my JSON template I'm using where you can view all my settings including my VPC, subnets, Security Groups, etc.: https://gist.github.com/dambrogia/e4cd93a64ae6f3a79d4a58d466f144f8

I am receiving a timeout error from the following command: (my `id_rsa` key is valid within ec2)

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ec2-user@<ec2_instance>
```

---

#### How can I SSH into my instances? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Thumbs up for including your actual CFN template! It really helps :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the CloudFormation template creates a `RouteTable` with the default route **0.0.0.0/0** correctly pointing to the **IGW**, however you don't associate the `RouteTable` with your subnets.

[image]

**What you need to do is add these two *Route Table Associations* to the template:**

```
        "Subnet1RT":{
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
                "Properties" : {
                    "RouteTableId" : { "Ref": "RouteTable" },
                    "SubnetId" : { "Ref": "Subnet1" }
                }
        },
        "Subnet2RT":{
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
                "Properties" : {
                    "RouteTableId" : { "Ref": "RouteTable" },
                    "SubnetId" : { "Ref": "Subnet2" }
                }
        },
```

Then *Update the stack* ...

[image]

And re-check the *Route Table*

[image]

Now you should be able to SSH to the instances:

```
~ $ ssh 54.209.123.119
Last login: Thu Nov  1 18:54:54 2018 from ...

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018.03-release-notes/
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-2-229 ~]$
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you *so* much for the in-depth answer and explanation. It worked like a charm!